# Kendo UI chart titles position right

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to get the my Kendo UI Chart title positioned to the right of the chart.  Is this possible?  I see in the docs it says "top" or "bottom" but has anyone figured out a way to put the titles to the right of the chart?

Comment: Do you want them rotated vertically like a y-axis title, or do you simply want it at the top but aligned to the top right corner instead of center aligned (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-title.align)?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good solution, but you cat do it through padding:

```
title: {
text: "Title",
padding: {
  top: 10,
  left: -100

}}
```